# How to animate a line chart in a streamlit page

Tags: python, matplotlib, streamlit

I am working with a ML project and I want to display in (relative) real time a chart with a fitness function.

I am using code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405499/real-time-matplotlib-plotting) and it works fine as long as the chart is displayed in the matplotlib window. As soon as I add it to the page, it becomes a static image.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

max_x = 5
max_rand = 10

x = np.arange(0, max_x)
ax.set_ylim(0, max_rand)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.random.randint(0, max_rand, max_x))


def init():  # give a clean slate to start
    line.set_ydata([np.nan] * len(x))
    return line,


def animate(i):  # update the y values (every 1000ms)
    line.set_ydata(np.random.randint(0, max_rand, max_x))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1000, blit=True, save_count=10)

st.pyplot(plt)
```

Any idea how to animate a chart? It doesn't have to be matplotlib.

Comment: Change the function `animate(i)` to update with your new chart data.

Comment: Yeah, this the first streamlit question ever on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I received my [answer on the streamlit forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-animate-a-line-chart/164/2) so I'm just copying the updated code here

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
import time

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

max_x = 5
max_rand = 10

x = np.arange(0, max_x)
ax.set_ylim(0, max_rand)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.random.randint(0, max_rand, max_x))
the_plot = st.pyplot(plt)

def init():  # give a clean slate to start
    line.set_ydata([np.nan] * len(x))

def animate(i):  # update the y values (every 1000ms)
    line.set_ydata(np.random.randint(0, max_rand, max_x))
    the_plot.pyplot(plt)

init()
for i in range(100):
    animate(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```